# Computing the ranges of floating point data types

Tags: c

Is it possible to compute the ranges of float, double and long double data types in a portable way without reading float.h and using ANSI C? By portable, I mean including those cases when the target machine does not adhere to IEEE 754 standard.

I'm reading the K&R book and exercise 2-1 asks me to "compute" them so I suppose that means avoiding float.h completely which includes FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX, DBL_MIN and DBL_MAX (reading these values directly would certainly not classify as "computing").

Comment: why do you think that means avoiding float.h ? well i think it wants you to use some function like ldexp, FLT_RADIX (or whatever it's called) and stuff

Comment: Well, because float.h already has the min/max values available which would seem like cheating in this case. But yeah, there are some other constants defined in float.h that could probably be used to determine the actual ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of a superfluous answer:

No.  There isn't a portable way to calculate the ranges.  That's why the `<float.h>` header is provided - because there isn't a portable way to derive the information contained in it.

Comment: That's true - but there are calculations which will work for a wide range of encoding schemes!

Answer (score 11):

It's possible (at least for IEEE 754 `float` and `double` values) to compute the greatest floating-point value via (pseudo-code):

```
~(-1.0) | 0.5
```

Before we can do our bit-twiddling, we'll have to convert the floating-point values to integers and then back again. This can be done in the following way:

```
uint64_t m_one, half;
double max;

*(double *)(void *)&m_one = -1.0;
*(double *)(void *)&half = 0.5;
*(uint64_t *)(void *)&max = ~m_one | half;
```

So how does it work? For that, we have to know how the floating-point values will be encoded.

The highest bit encodes the sign, the next `k` bits encode the exponent and the lowest bits will hold the fractional part. For powers of `2`, the fractional part is `0`.

The exponent will be stored with a bias (offset) of `2**(k-1) - 1`, which means an exponent of `0` corresponds to a pattern with all but the highest bit set.

There are two exponent bit patterns with special meaning:

- if no bit is set, the value will be `0` if the fractional part is zero; otherwise, the value is a subnormal
- if all bits are set, the value is either `infinity` or `NaN`

This means the greatest regular exponent will be encoded via setting all bits except the lowest one, which corresponds to a value of `2**k - 2` or `2**(k-1) - 1` if you substract the bias.

For `double` values, `k = 11`, ie the highest exponent will be `1023`, so the greatest floating point value is of order `2**1023` which is about `1E+308`.

The greatest value will have

- the sign bit set to `0`
- all but the lowest exponent bit set to `1`
- all fractional bits set to `1`

Now, it's possible to understand how our magic numbers work:

- `-1.0` has its sign bit set, the exponent is the bias - ie all bits but the highest one are present - and the fractional part is `0`
- `~(-1.0)` has only the highest exponent bit and all fractional bits set
- `0.5` has a sign bit and fractional part of `0`; the exponent will be the bias minus `1`, ie all but the highest and lowest exponent bits will be present

When we combine these two values via logical or, we'll get the bit pattern we wanted.

---

The computation works for x86 80-bit extended precision values (aka `long double`) as well, but the bit-twiddling must be done byte-wise as there's no integer type large enough to hold the values on 32-bit hardware.

The bias isn't actually required to be `2**(k-1) - 1` - it'll work for an arbitrary bias as long as it is odd. The bias must be odd because otherwise the bit-patterns for the exponent of `1.0` and `0.5` will differ in other places than the lowest bit.

If the base `b` (aka radix) of the floating-point type is not `2`, you have to use `b**(-1)` instead of `0.5 = 2**(-1)`.

If the greatest exponent value is not reserverd, use `1.0` instead of `0.5`. This will work regardless of base or bias (meaning it's no longer restricted to odd values). The difference in using `1.0` is that the lowest exponent bit won't be cleared.

---

To summarize:

```
~(-1.0) | 0.5
```

works as long as the radix is `2`, the bias is odd and the highest exponent is reserved.

```
~(-1.0) | 1.0
```

works for any radix or bias as long as the highest exponent is not reserved.

Comment: Saying "for IEEE 754" denies the premise of the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: at 'least for' wasn'tmeant to mean 'only for' - this works for every floating-point value with a bias of `2**(k-1) - 1` and a reserved exponent of `2**k - 1`, which includes half and quadruple precision values as well as 80-bit extended precision values on x86

Comment: @Jonathan: How else do you want to 'compute' something if you don't restrict the possible encoding schemes? There just isn't an algorithm which will work for all encodings!

Answer (score 4):

For 99.99% of all applications, you should assume IEEE 754 and use the constants defined in `<float.h>`.  In the other 0.01%, you'll be working with very specialized hardware, and in that case, you should know what to use based on the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a float bigger until it overflows.

Comment: That's what I've been doing with integer types - but wouldn't it take quite some time to overflow a long double?

Comment: If you do it by exponential search, it will overflow fast enough. You can even make the number grow faster (eg. exponential search of maximum exponent vs. exponential search of maximum value)